# Unblocked streaming port?

Tags: port, video-streaming

Every year we hold a music concert in a hotel ballroom.

My setup is the camera input going into a transcoding computer that is then relayed to my streaming server off location, which is then served to the clients.

Everything works well when I tried the setup from home, but at the event the hotel's internet connection was blocking every port I tried on my local transcoding computer.

Is there any ports that "usually" is open and available? The hotel staff know nothing and couldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is 80, then try 8080

Comment: I did try 8080, and I was under the impression that http being on 80 would block it from other programs using it? Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: also try port 443. you can have more than one port on a connection - else web servers wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have the permission of the hotel staff, there's various ways to determine what ports are free - [nmap](http://nmap.org/) for example or grc's [shieldsup](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) web service.

If there's absolutely no free ports whatsoever, i might ponder testing [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) since in addition to being a VPN software, it uses various techiques to work inside a firewall